# ASP.NET MVC3 ViewData and HTML breaks when adding model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is a ASP.NET MVC4 Application using ASPX view engine. I can start with a fresh project and Import a reference to My DataManager and when I do that it breaks ViewData and HTML.x statements.. Below is the line where I am adding it:

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of Data_Manager.Conf_Info" %>
```

And this is a screen shot of what is happening to ViewData

[image: Screenshot of ViewData]

And the current Project References are:

[image]

It should be noted that I tried a stock MVC4 Application using aspx and went straight in and added the reference to the DLL and the above line and it broke immediately..

Having said that the Below is the references that the DLL uses..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing bracket for Your ViewPage generic type:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of Data_Manager.Conf_Info)"
```

Comment: Thanks much, dunno why I overlooked it.. That issue is resolved but I am seeing a new one now.. New Question time